# Correct function calling with two var

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have php function calling 2 variables for controlling active links. I don't know is it written correctly and how to call it in my other script.

My function is in functions.php and my navigation is in nav.php. I includ both in index.php.

Function:

```
function active_links() {

  // stranice = Active //
  if (isset($_GET['poslovni_korisnici'])) {
    $active1 = 'class="active"';
  } else {
    $active1 = '';
  }
  if (isset($_GET['korisnici'])) {
    $active2 = 'class="active"';
  } else {
    $active2 = '';
  }
}
```

nav.php

```
<body>
  <!-- start body -->

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <!-- start nav -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">POSLOVNA STATISTIKA</a>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li ' . $active . '><a href="index.php?poslovni_korisnici">Poslovni korisnici <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li ' . $active . '><a href="index.php?korisnici">Korisnici</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
```

index.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'functions.php';

$dbh = connect_to_database();

$active =  active_links();


include 'includes/head.php';

include 'includes/nav.php';
```

Comment: Are you not "calling" the `active_links()` function? What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: Your `active_links()` is setting `$active1` and `$active2` but in your `nav1 .php` you are referring to `$active`

Answer (score 1):

end `active_links()` with

```
return(array($active1,$active2));
```

then

```
$active =  active_links();
```

`$active` will be an array with 2 variables to use:

`$active[0]` and `$active[1]`

Comment: i put return in function and $active[0] and $active[1] in nav...is that correct? it isnt working

Comment: *isnt working* sorry but how can i possibly help based on that description?

Comment: sry! $active =  active_links(); i put in index page, return(array($active1,$active2)); at the end of function in functions.php and i edit nav.php like this  <li ' . $active[0] . '><a href="index.php?poslovni_korisnici">Poslovni korisnici <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li ' . $active[1] . '><a href="index.php?korisnici">Korisnici</a></li>

Comment: is that correct or? nothing is happening it isnt working

Comment: Have you seen the development env. And what the att. of you li tag?